# Property of poisson point process

Tags: limits, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

In my statistics textbook I found that one of the properties of a Poisson point process is the following:

Let $N(t)$ denote the number of events that occur in the time interval $[0, t]$. These events are said to constitute a Poisson process having rate $\lambda , \lambda > 0$ if amongst other things:

$$\lim_{h \longrightarrow 0} \frac{P(N(h) = 1)}{h} = \lambda$$

How do I prove this? What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: The proof depends on your definition of Poisson process. For example, do you define it as counting a sequence of arrivals (starting from time 0), where arrivals have  i.i.d. exponentially distributed inter-arrival times of parameter $\lambda$? Then $P[N(h)=1]$ is the probability that the first arrival is in the interval $[0,h]$ and the second arrival is at time larger than $h$.

Comment: Yes I do define it as such.

Comment: So you can use $P[N(h)=1] = \int_0^{\infty} P[N(h)=1|X_1=x]\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$.

Comment: The intuition is that if the rate is $\lambda$ then the expected number of events in time interval $h$ is $\lambda h$.  When $h$ is small then $\lambda h$ is also small, and the probability of two or more events in the interval is very small,  so you are close to having ${P(N(h) = 1)} = \lambda h$ and ${P(N(h) = 0)} = 1-\lambda h$

Comment: It's not clear what you want to prove. What is given appears to be intended as a definition rather than as a theorem. Do you want a proof of its equivalence to other characterizations of the Poisson distribution?

Comment: This way of using the word "event" puts a heavy burden on that word, since it's different from the most usual use of that word in probability theory. That's one reason to prefer the word "arrival".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exact calculation:**

You can calculate $P[N(h)=1]$ exactly by conditioning on the time of the first arrival
$$ P[N(h)=1] = \int_0^{\infty} P[N(h)=1\mid X_1=x]\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$$

**Intuitive calculation:**

You can intuitively understand because we know
$$ E[N(h)] = \lambda h \quad \forall h>0 \tag{Eq. 1}$$
But if $h$ is positive and close to $0$, we get either $0$ or $1$ arrival in time $h$ (with negligible probability of getting more than $1$ arrival) so
\begin{align}
E[N(h)] &= 0\cdot P[N(h)=0] + 1\cdot P[N(h)=1] + 2\cdot P[N(h)=2] + \cdots \\
&\approx 0\cdot P[N(h)=0] + 1\cdot P[N(h)=1]
\end{align}
and combining with (Eq. 1) gives
$P[N(h)=1] \approx \lambda h$.